# How to import an android aar library in a cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, build.gradle

I am building a cordova plugin (wrapper) for an existing premium mobile SDK

I have started with Android, based on various tutorials available at the moment

So far, I've successfully set up the local cordova plugin project and the cordova test app and I test the js binding between the cordova app and my dummy java plugin wrapper implementation

Moving forward, I have to add multiple aar dependencies in the plugin, which I expect shall be automatically configured in the cordova android app's gradle build scripts when adding the plug-in with 'cordova plugin add /path/to/my/local/plugin'

However, in practice, it seems I have not found the right way to do so, and all the answers and instructions related to the matter required manual edit of the build.gradle file

As shown in the [crodova dependencies configuration documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#source-file), in my plugin.xml file, I've added:

```
 <platform name="android">
     ......
     <source-file framework="true" 
                  src="native-libs/android/myNativeLib.aar"
                  target-dir="libs"/>
 </platform>
```

My expectancy was that, on top of copying the .aar file in the target /libs directory, the setting of the attribute 'framework=true' would also result in 'cordova plugin add /path/to/local/plugin/' automatically generating the boilerplate build.gradle configs:

Enable local dependencies repository

```
repositories {
    ...
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

As well as configuring the prescribed aar gradle dependencies

```
dependencies{
    .....
    compile(name: 'myNativeLib', ext: 'aar')
    .....
}
```

The thing is, the whole purpose of writing the plugin is for it to work as-is, like any premium integration experience - without any other special set-up instructions

I am really curious if this is currently possible with cordova, or eventually I could attempt to contribute to the project with such a new feature

Looking forward to learning more about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `framework` property is iOS only in my experience at is also marked as an iOS property in the docs you linked.

As you already mentioned any user would expect the plugin to work without any setup after adding it which is why you don't want him to fiddle around in the `platforms` folder. To make this work you can extend cordovas gradle file. You have to add a framework tag to your `plugin.xml` which is of type `gradleReference` and links to your gradle extension (the path is relative to your `plugin.xml`):

```
<framework src="src/android/*.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

The resulting gradle-extension will look something like this:

```
repositories {    
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name: 'myNativeLib', ext: 'aar')
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

This assumes that you have put your `.aar` library in a subdirectory of your plugin named `libs`.

Comment: Indeed this is a good workaround as it would prevent the manual edit of the build.gradle file; however, the aar configuration still remains sloppy: add aar copy instruction for each lib, then add build script extension for each lib. And I have 10+ aars to add. I'm looking for a single config entry for each dependency or maybe even beyond that, one entry for everything in the libs folder

Comment: This is not a workaround, this is the way it is designed to work. You do not need to add 10 gradle extension files for 10 aar libs, you can put it all into one file. You will not find something simpler until the cordova team is done refactoring the project-structure of the cordova projects. This is a WIP at the moment but will probably still take some time.

Comment: I mean you still have to have an entry to copy the aar and another entry in the gradle file to link it

Comment: Yeah well, at some point there will be a little effort for configuration, you will not come around that :-) You have to do it once and then it will work out of the box for your customers, thats kind of the ‚price‘ of such an extendible and configurable framework like cordova.

Comment: Okay, I'll mark this as an answer, since it seems there's no better way to achieve the goal